# recycler view with different images from serverdata

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-drawable, android-recyclerview

I get a string out of my server request for one item in my recyclerview and it gives me PDF Word or Image. Now I want to display different images in my recyclerviewitem for each String. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ScriptViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ItemObject currentScript = scriptObjects.get(position);

    holder.scriptName.setText(currentScript.getScriptName());
    holder.scriptDate.setText(currentScript.getScriptDate());
    holder.scriptUser.setText(currentScript.getScriptUser());

    String whichformat = currentScript.getScriptFormat();
    switch (whichformat) {
        case "PDF":
            imagename = "ic_picture_as_pdf_black_24dp.png";
        case "Word":
            imagename = "ic_insert_drive_file_black_24dp.png";
        case "Image":
            imagename = "ic_photo_library_black_24dp.png";
    }

    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, null , null );
    holder.scriptIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resourceId));
```

I get an error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.ndlp.socialstudy, PID: 3481
                                                                    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

and it points to my recycler adapter class and to:

```
holder.scriptIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resourceId));
```

Do you know what I did wrong? The imagenames like in the switch are right I already checked them.

I also already tried:

```
 int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable" , context.getPackageName() );
```

Kind regards

hellownero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should get resourceId with this manner:

```
switch (whichformat) {
        case "PDF":
            imagename = "ic_picture_as_pdf_black_24dp";
        case "Word":
            imagename = "ic_insert_drive_file_black_24dp";
        case "Image":
            imagename = "ic_photo_library_black_24dp";
}

int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

You got this exception because you pass `null` as `defType` and `packageName`. you don't need to pass file type as the image name.

Comment: Thanks for your time appreciate it a lot but I already tried this (see my edit at the bottom) and the error stays the same...

Comment: @PatrickNadler did you tried to remove `.png` from the end of the file name?

Comment: thanks it works somehow but the image that is displayed is always the library image even with items that have the string PDF do u have any suggestions how to solve that?

Comment: Your welcome, the problem solved, check your `whichformat` and make sure it's correct and don't have any issue.

Comment: the whichformat is correct. I tested it with an on click on the items and give it out they are all one of the 3 strings but all have the same image.... Any suggestions on that one? dont understand wh this is the case